# exit() gets printed instead of stopping the web page

Tags: php, include, exit, exit-code, php-include

**set_then_exit.php**

```
<?php

$_SESSION['third_pen'] = 'unhanded';

//similar codes

exit();
```

**notes.php**

```
<?php

if(true)
{
     include_once dirname(__FILE__)."/set_then_exit.php";
}
```

I tried

```
<?php

if(true)
{
     include_once dirname(__FILE__)."/set.php";
     exit();
}
```

Yes, it works. But I wanted being DRY so I made `set_then_exit.php` and replaced `set.php`. I have other files that contains this snippet. And to my surprise `exit()` just get printed. Any idea why is it so?

Thanks.

**UPDATE -**
*Thanks for the comments +1.*

`set_then_exit.php` is similar to `set.php`, the only difference is the `exit()` in the end of  `set_then_exit.php`.

Comment: All PHP code needs to start with `<?php`.  If the entire file is going to be PHP, just put `<?php` on the first line.  If it isn't there, then it will just be interpreted as plain text.

Comment: its there. wait. i'll put the `<?php` to make it clear. thanks.

Comment: Do you close the PHP tag in `//similar codes`?

Comment: no. in `//similar codes` I just assigned other session variables.

Comment: and oh, `set_then_exit.php` is similar to `set.php`, the only difference is the `exit()` in the end of  `set_then_exit.php`.

Comment: Well, sorry, but you must be doing something you haven't said, like closing PHP mode somehow, including code through a web server or using short tags in a system where they aren't enabled. Unless you're able to share actual code that reproduces the issue we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Ok I'll check. I'll update later.

Comment: PHP works, otherwise I wont be able to use `include()`, `if()`, set session variables inside the `include()`, or anything at all that is PHP. And `exit()` works when not inside an `include()`. I tried replicating it with just a simple include and still got the same results. I'm starting to think that this is actually how `exit()` behaves inside an `include()`. hahah. *smh.